# There are some parts that I don't understand well about Flutter's Key

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I practiced after watching a video explaining Flutter's Key.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html

This video shows an example of changing the location of a container with a specific color. (About 1 minute and 50 seconds)

In the video, the statefulwidget says that without a key, the location will not change.

But I wrote the example code myself and confirmed that it worked without giving a key to the stateful widget.

I think I wrote the example code wrong. Below is the code I wrote.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: KeyPractice(),
    );
  }
}

class StatefulColorfulTile extends StatefulWidget {
  StatefulColorfulTile({@required this.color});

  final Color color;

  @override
  _StatefulColorfulTileState createState() => _StatefulColorfulTileState();
}

class _StatefulColorfulTileState extends State<StatefulColorfulTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: widget.color,
    );
  }
}

class KeyPractice extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KeyPracticeState createState() => _KeyPracticeState();
}

class _KeyPracticeState extends State<KeyPractice> {
  List<Widget> tiles;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tiles = [
      StatefulColorfulTile(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
      ),
      StatefulColorfulTile(
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: tiles,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.autorenew,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            tiles.insert(1, tiles.removeAt(0));
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The above codes switch positions with each other.

What happens to the example of how the widget does not reposition each other when the stateful widget in the video does not assign keys?

And I understand that the key works only on the Stateful widget, does the Stateless use the key?

And I understood that Key only works with the Stateful widget. I wonder if the Stateless widget uses a key.

If I misunderstood, please teach me.

Comment: You're storing the color in the `State` of `KeyPractice`. The example they use stores it in the state of the child, in your case: `StatefulColorfulTile`.

Comment: I thought it was a problem, so I assigned a color state to the child widget, but I still changed each other's widget. could you show me the example code? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I didn't actually make example, I just noticed your issue. Would you like me to create one?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the color in the `State` of `KeyPractice`. The example they use stores it in the `State` of the child, in your case: `StatefulColorfulTile`.

Below is an example of the use of keys to correctly reposition widgets like you're trying to do. My example ended up very similar to what's shown on this [medium article](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d). Removing the keys here prevents the widgets from reflecting the color swap, but the use of the keys allows for the intended behavior.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: KeyPractice(),
    );
  }
}

class StatefulColorfulTile extends StatefulWidget {
  StatefulColorfulTile({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  _StatefulColorfulTileState createState() => _StatefulColorfulTileState();
}

class _StatefulColorfulTileState extends State<StatefulColorfulTile> {
  final Color myColor = UniqueColorGenerator.getColor();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: myColor,
    );
  }
}

class KeyPractice extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KeyPracticeState createState() => _KeyPracticeState();
}

class _KeyPracticeState extends State<KeyPractice> {
  List<Widget> tiles;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tiles = [
      StatefulColorfulTile(key: UniqueKey()),
      StatefulColorfulTile(key: UniqueKey()),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: tiles,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.autorenew,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            tiles.insert(1, tiles.removeAt(0));
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


class UniqueColorGenerator {
  static Random random = new Random();
  static Color getColor() {
    return Color.fromARGB(255, random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255));
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm so glad you replied. I will study it again based on what you told me. I'm thinking of writing a blog about this, can I reveal the source of the code and quote it?

Comment: @Jay-flow You can do that without my permission according to the [licenses for posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) as long as you give appropriate credit. However, I must mention I took the color generator from somewhere else and it ended up looking *very* similar to the code in the medium article I linked.